# RestKit Errors after Xcode crash

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, compiler-errors, restkit

I've been using RestKit in a project for the last couple of months without any issues. I have it set up as per the instructions on the Github wiki. Today Xcode hung while connecting to the simulator. I had just edited some trivial UI code completely unrelated to anything touching RestKit. I had to force quit Xcode and restart. When I restarted and compiled again, RestKit built successfully but I got a string of Errors related to my application. On closer inspection they are all related to RestKit. There are a cascade of errors starting in RKRequestSerializable then spreading out to every RestKit class that references it.

The first error is 'Expected a type' for the line:

```
 @protocol RKRequestSerializable
```

then 'Expected selector for Objective-C method' for the line:

```
 - (NSString*)HTTPHeaderValueForContentType;
```

then 'Expected a method body' for:

```
 @optional
```

The first thing I did was revert the changes I had made since the last successful compile, but this made no difference. I then rolled RestKit back in case I had accidentally made a change, but this had no effect. I have tried deleting derived data, deleting and re-adding RestKit, but nothing has any effect. My project will not compile.

The strangest thing is that RestKit compiles successfully. The errors are from the compilation of my project. I've lost three hours on this so far and would greatly appreciate any input or suggestions as to how I might solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still building for the simulator? I've seen this behavior after an XCode crash. The Schema gets set to OS X 64 bit or something else and RestKit doesn't compile there.

Comment: You're spot on. RestKit had been switched to compile to OSX. Xcode crashes on me maybe 20 times a day so I'm surprised that never happened before. Many thanks.